# Algorithm for Permutation with Buckets

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I am looking for an algorithm which works like this

```
permutateBuckets([A,B,C])
```

and gives the following result:

```
[ [[A,B,C]],
  [[A,B],[C]], [[A,C],[B]], [[B,C],[A]], [[A],[B,C]], [[B],[A,C]], [[C],[A,B]],
  [[A],[B],[C]], [[A],[C],[B]], [[B],[A],[C]], [[B],[C],[A]], [[C],[A],[B]], [[C],[B],[A]]
]
```

In general:

The permutation for [1,2,...,n] should include any possible arrangements of 1 up to n buckets that contain the input values, order of values within buckets is not relevant (e.g. [1,2] equals [2,1]), only the order of the containing buckets matters (e.g. [[1,2],[3]] is different than [[3],[1,2]] ).

Each input element has to be in exactly one bucket for a result to be valid (e.g. an input of [1,2] cannot give [[1]] (missing 2), or [[1,2],[1]] (1 appears twice) as output).

Comment: A recursive approach is certainly easier, but maybe not the most efficient solution. Would you be happy with such recursive approach? (I have not a solution, just to know what you expect).

Comment: I also thought that a recursive approach would be the most efficient way - I'm fine with either recursive or sequencial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is recursive:

```
 Make [[A]] list
 Insert new item in all possible places - 
    before current sublists
    between all sublists
    after current sublists
    into every sublist
```

For example, list `[[B][A]]` produces 5 new lists with item C - places to insert C are:

```
  [   [B]   [A]   ]
    ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

and three level-2 lists `[[A],[B]], [[B],[A]], [[A,B]]` produce 5+5+3=13 level-3 lists.

Alternative way:
Generate all n-length nondecreasing sequences from 1...1 to 1..n and generate unique permutations for every sequence. 
Values on these permutations correspond to the bucket number for every item. For example, 122 sequence gives 3 permutations that corresponds to distributions:

```
1 2 2     [1],[2, 3] 
2 1 2     [2],[1, 3] 
2 2 1     [3],[1, 2]
```

In any case number of distributions rises very quickly (ordered Bell numbers `1, 3, 13, 75, 541, 4683, 47293, 545835, 7087261, 102247563...`)

Implementation of iterative approach in Delphi  (full FP-compatible code at [ideone](https://ideone.com/oTqUAo))

```
 procedure GenDistributions(N: Integer);
  var
    seq, t, i, mx: Integer;
    Data: array of Byte;
    Dist: TBytes2D;
  begin
    SetLength(Data, N);

    //there are n-1 places for incrementing
    //so 2^(n-1) possible sequences
    for seq := 0 to 1 shl (N - 1) - 1 do begin
      t := seq;
      mx := 0;
      Data[0] := mx;
      for i := 1 to N - 1 do begin
        mx := mx + (t and 1); //check for the lowest bit
        Data[i] := mx;
        t := t shr 1;
      end;

      //here Data contains nondecreasing sequence 0..mx, increment is 0 or 1
      //Data[i] corresponds to the number of sublist which item i belongs to

      repeat
        Dist := nil;
        SetLength(Dist, mx + 1); // reset result array into [][][] state

        for i := 0 to N - 1 do
          Dist[Data[i]] := Dist[Data[i]] + [i]; //add item to calculated sublist

        PrintOut(Dist);
      until not NextPerm(Data);  //generates next permutation if possible

    end;
```

And now Python recursive implementation ([ideone](https://ideone.com/1in2Eb))

```
import copy
cnt = 0

def ModifySublist(Ls, idx, value):
    res = copy.deepcopy(Ls)
    res[idx].append(value)
    return res

def InsertSublist(Ls, idx, value):
    res = copy.deepcopy(Ls)
    res.insert(idx, [value])
    return res

def GenDists(AList, Level, Limit):
    global cnt
    if (Level==Limit):
        print( AList)
        cnt += 1
    else:
        for i in range(len(AList)):
            GenDists(ModifySublist(AList, i, Level), Level + 1, Limit)
            GenDists(InsertSublist(AList, i, Level), Level + 1, Limit)
        GenDists(InsertSublist(AList, len(AList), Level), Level + 1, Limit)

GenDists([], 0, 3)
print(cnt)
```

Edit: @mhmnn cloned this code in [JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/gvf2dg9e/) using custom items for output.

Comment: I will try to code that approach tomorrow and post my results, thank you!

Comment: I implemented it in JavaScript based on your Python code, and extended it by accepting an array with values which gets permutated. Code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/gvf2dg9e/
Feel free to add the code to your answer for more visibility - note that Lodash.js is used for the cloneDeep function.