# Number of ways to fill an array of size n , such that the mexium is greater than every element of the array?

Tags: arrays, math

We have given an empty array of size n , we need to fill it with natural numbers (we are allowed to repeat).
The condition that must follow is the **mex** of the array must be greater than all the elements we fill in the array .
Can someone pls help me with the number of ways to do so ?
(Different arrangements of same set of numbers are also considered distinct)

PS:- by mex of a sequence I mean the smallest non negative number that doesn't occur in the sequence

Comment: Assuming array elements must be ≥ 0, then the answer is `mex^n`, because each element in the array can take all values from 0 to mex-1

Comment: @derpirscher as I understand it "mex" is a property of the selected numbers, not a constant. eg `mex([5,0,3,4]) = 1` since 1 is the smallest non-negative value not in {5,0,3,4}. This means you can't predetermine `mex` and then get `mex^n` values.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson  but then what is meant by "*the mex must be greater than all the elements we fill in the array*"/ In your case, the only value you can fill into the array, would be `0`?

Comment: @derpirscher I read it as "The condition that must follow is the mex *of the array* must be greater than all the elements we fill in the array" an "PS:- by the mex of the *array* I mean the smallest non negative number that doesn't occur in the *array*".

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Ah, now I get it. In this case, my comments are, of course, complete nonsense :) thx. for the clarification ... Made a small edit to the original question to point that out specifically.

Comment: @derpirscher sorry if I was unclear with the language , what I basically meant was there should not be any value which is not in the array but values greater than it exists in the array . But still can't see how you arrive at filling with 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of such arrays is equivalent to the number of ordered distributions of values `1..N` into buckets (so `[A],[B,C]` and `[B,C][A]` are distinct ones). And number of such distributions is described by [ordered Bell numbers 1,3,13,75...](http://oeis.org/A000670).

Example for N=3

```
1 1 1    //1 permutation
1 1 2    //3 permutations
1 2 2    //3 permutations
1 2 3    //6 permutations
        //13 variants
```

[Generation of distributions themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376466/algorithm-for-permutation-with-buckets/47377101#47377101) for reference. Note that for `N` values every value might fall into part `1..K`, where `K` is in range `1..N`, so numbers of parts corresponding to all values form continuous sequence without holes (cf. your `mex`)

To calculate number of such distributions, we can use [recurrence from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number#Recurrence_and_modular_periodicity), Python code:

```
def cnk(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k <= 0:
        return 1 if k == 0 else 0
    res = 1
    for i in range(k):
        res = res * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return res

def orderedbell(n):
    a = [0]*(n+1)
    a[0] = 1
    for m in range(1, n+1):
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            a[m] += cnk(m, i) * a[m - i]
    return a[n]

for i in range(1,10):
    print(orderedbell(i))

1
3
13
75
541
4683
47293
545835
7087261
```

Comment: Could you explain the intuition behind the equivalence?

Comment: @Dave I believe that the second paragraph `Note that..`  in short describes equivalence - we can choose any `mex` in range `2..N+1`. Value `mex-1` corresponds to the number of parts/buckets. `Arr[i]` value is less than `mex` and corresponds to the index of bucket for i-th item. Array must contain all the values in  range `1..mex-1` (perhaps with repeats). This fact corresponds to natural bucket indexing without holes.